How can I build a Gift Wrapping Station in Hay Day?
How can I build a Gift Wrapping Station in Hay Day?

According to the Fandom,

The Gift Wrapping Station is a production building unlocked at experience level 17.  [...] It does not need to be repaired or bought. It is given for free, that delivered by Alfred the Mailman

It also disappears automatically after the 31st of every (IRL) year.
